# How to show to average sales for each year within ten years for a specific city in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

What would be the correct way to show what was the average sales volume in Carlisle city for each year between
2010-2020?

Here is an abbreviated form of the large data frame showing only the columns and rows relevant to the question:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/09/2009','01/10/2009','01/11/2009','01/12/2009','01/01/2010','01/02/2010','01/03/2010','01/04/2010','01/05/2010','01/06/2010','01/07/2010','01/08/2010','01/09/2010','01/10/2010','01/11/2010','01/12/2010','01/01/2011','01/02/2011'],
                   'RegionName': ['Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle','Carlisle'],
                    'SalesVolume': [118,137,122,132,83,81,105,114,110,106,137,130,129,121,129,100,84,62]})
```

This is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv ('C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/uk_hpi_dataset_2021_01.csv')

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda x:
                                               '{year}'.format(year=x.year).zfill(2))

carlisle_vol = df[df['RegionName'].str.contains('Carlisle')]
carlisle_vol.groupby('Year')['SalesVolume'].mean()

print(sales_vol)
```

When I try to run this code, it doesn't filter the 'Date' column to only calculate the average SalesVolume for the years beginning in '01/01/2010' and ending at '01/12/2020'. For some reason, it also prints out every other column is well. Can anyone please help me to answer this question correctly?

[This is the result I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMUeb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access year with the [datetime accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors):

```py
df[
    (df["RegionName"] == "Carlisle")
    & (df["Date"].dt.year >= 2010)
    & (df["Date"].dt.year <= 2020)
].groupby(df.Date.dt.year)["SalesVolume"].mean()

>>>

Date
2010    112.083333
2011     73.000000
Name: SalesVolume, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This code is also working perfectly, thanks for your effort! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df.loc[(df["Date"].dt.year.between(2010, 2020))
           & (df["RegionName"] == "Carlisle")] \
  .groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="Y")])["SalesVolume"].mean()

Date
2010-01-01    112.083333
2011-01-01     73.000000
Freq: A-DEC, Name: SalesVolume, dtype: float64
```

**For further**:

The only difference between the answer of @nocibambi is the `groupby` parameter and particularly the `freq` argument of `pd.Grouper`. Imagine your accounting year starts the 1st september.

Sales each 3 months:

```
>>> df
        Date  Sales
0 2010-09-01      1  # 1st group: mean=2.5
1 2010-12-01      2
2 2011-03-01      3
3 2011-06-01      4
4 2011-09-01      5  # 2nd group: mean=6.5
5 2011-12-01      6
6 2012-03-01      7
7 2012-06-01      8

>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="AS-SEP")).mean()
            Sales
Date
2010-09-01    2.5
2011-09-01    6.5
```

Check the documentation to know all values of `freq` [aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) and [anchoring suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets)

Comment: This code is working fine but it shows the average for every region between 2010-2020 instead of just Carlisle. However, I eventually managed to fix it so, thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: I fixed my answer and give some explanation about `pd.Grouper`